# Can Python update Passwords for Oracle SQL Developer Connections

Tags: python, oracle, passwords, oracle-sqldeveloper

My Python script updates Oracle passwords regularly using the command
    `alter user my_user` identified by `"new_password"` replace `"old_password"`
Now I need to update these passwords in the `SQL Developer connection definitions`. I have looked all over my Windows 7 machine but nowhere can I find `Connections.xml`, nor `IDEConnections.xml`. And if so, the passwords would be encrypted.

Can anybody automate password updates for SQL Developer?

Answer (score 1):

The file is called `connections.xml` and on Windows is located in:

```
"%appdata%\Roaming\SQL Developer\system<some-numbers>\o.jdeveloper.db.connection.<some-other-numbers>\connections.xml"
```

For example:

```
C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Roaming\SQL Developer\system3.2.20.09.87\o.jdeveloper.db.connection.11.1.1.4.37.59.48\connections.xml
```

There you will find entities like this:

```
<Reference name="XXXXXXX" className="oracle.jdeveloper.db.adapter.DatabaseProvider" xmlns="">
  <Factory className="oracle.jdeveloper.db.adapter.DatabaseProviderFactory"/>
  <RefAddresses>
    ...
    <StringRefAddr addrType="ConnName">
        <Contents>MY DATABASE</Contents>
     </StringRefAddr>
     <StringRefAddr addrType="customUrl">
        <Contents>jdbc:oracle:thin:@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:1521:service_name</Contents>
     </StringRefAddr>
     <StringRefAddr addrType="password">
        <Contents>0540C826BDC964bFF7C1E309587AAA35D53B34ACAC8A595A52</Contents>
     </StringRefAddr>
  </RefAddresses>
```

The hash is DES cipher - some examples here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18021526/9655177. It is a decryption example, but you can reverse it.

Comment: Robertus, as I said, there is no file "Connections.xml" on my Windows 7 workstation. The path you provided fails on the "system<vers no> directory. I did find a file `C:\Users\wmetzner01\AppData\Roaming\sqldeveloper\4.1.5\product.conf` it looks like a configuration file; however, all text lines are commented with hash (#). Thanks @robertus

Comment: oh, I found the `connections.xml` and the `product-preferences.xml` files on my workstation; they are hidden system files. THANKS. Now I need to figure out the encryption that SQL Developer 4.1.5 uses.

Answer (score 0):

Robertus post pointed me in the right direction as to the location of the relevant configuration files; however, the password encryption is not solved yet. Re-opening a new question.