# SQL Developer V19 - Decrypt Password from Connections XML

Tags: java, passwords, oracle-sqldeveloper

I had a Java code to decrypt password stored in connections XML for SQL Developer V17.
Looks like the encryption method or details are changed for V19.
After updating to SQL Developer V19, the same old code is not working.
Anyone know how to decrypt the password stored in connections XML for SQL Developer V19?

Comment: One way is export them with old version of SQLDeveloper, then import with new version of SQLDeveloper, if you do not pretend to install old version again.

Comment: Thanks, I did export and imported. However, I used that Java code to decrypt , when I need to verify the password I have and the one that is deployed are same, while triaging issues or if I need to share the details with others in team.

Comment: look at another similar question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1032721/294674)

Answer (score 0):

1. Get encrypted password from connections.json file from location :
   **C:\Users<User name>\AppData\Roaming\SQL
   Developer\system18.4.0.376.1900\o.jdeveloper.db.connection** Example :
   "password": "Ehi21wFkasdfc=",
2. Get the ecryption key from the file
   product-preferences.xml in location **C:\Users<user
   name>\AppData\Roaming\SQL
   Developer\system18.4.0.376.1900\o.sqldeveloper**

   Example :
3. decrypt the password using the below website.

https://abskmj.github.io/sqldev-pw-decryptor/

Answer (score 0):

Alternative way to do it in local machine:

1. Get encrypted password from connections.json file from location :
   C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\SQL
   Developer\system18.4.0.376.1900\o.jdeveloper.db.connection Example :
   "password": "Ehi21wFkasdfc=",
2. Get the ecryption key from the file product-preferences.xml in
   location C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\SQL
   Developer\system18.4.0.376.1900\o.sqldeveloper
3. Use the following code to decrypt the password

   ```
    package utils;
    import java.security.MessageDigest;
    import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
    import javax.crypto.Cipher;
    import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
    import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
    import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;
    import java.util.Base64;

   public class Decrypt_OracleSqlDevPW {
    private static byte[] des_cbc_decrypt(
             byte[] encrypted_password,
             byte[] decryption_key,
             byte[] iv)
             throws GeneralSecurityException
             {

            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
             cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, new SecretKeySpec(decryption_key, "DES"), new IvParameterSpec(iv));
             return cipher.doFinal(encrypted_password);
            }

            private static byte[] decrypt_v4(
             byte[] encrypted,
             byte[] db_system_id)
             throws GeneralSecurityException
             {
            byte[] encrypted_password = Base64.getDecoder().decode(encrypted);
            byte[] salt = DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary("051399429372e8ad");

            // key = db_system_id + salt
             byte[] key = new byte[db_system_id.length + salt.length];
             System.arraycopy(db_system_id, 0, key, 0, db_system_id.length);
             System.arraycopy(salt, 0, key, db_system_id.length, salt.length);

            java.security.MessageDigest md = java.security.MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
             for (int i=0; i<42; i++) {
             key = md.digest(key);
             }

            // secret_key = key [0..7]
             byte[] secret_key = new byte[8];
             System.arraycopy(key, 0, secret_key, 0, 8);

            // iv = key [8..]
             byte[] iv = new byte[key.length - 8];
             System.arraycopy(key, 8, iv, 0, key.length - 8);

            return des_cbc_decrypt(encrypted_password, secret_key, iv);
             }

            public static void main(String[] argv) { try {

            String encryptedPassword = "wwA5s2bU02lfY4aTg==";// password
            String key = "8397631a-9e0f-42-afda-3fafcac1f193";//key in our local machine

            byte[] encrypted = encryptedPassword.getBytes();
             byte[] db_system_id = key.getBytes();

            byte[] x = decrypt_v4(encrypted, db_system_id);

            String password = new String(x);

            System.out.println(password);
             }
             catch (Exception e) {
             System.out.println(e.toString());
             }
             }
   ```

   }

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQL Developer extension called **Show Me Password**.

1. Download the [extension](https://show-me-password.tomecode.com/) 'zip'
2. Install the extension

> - Help -> Check for Updates
> - Install From Local File(s)
> - Browse for the downloaded zip file of the extension then hit '*Next*'
> - Restart SQL Developer

3. Go to '*File*' -> '*Show Me Password*'